# Looking for Philip Pullman quote re imaginary numbers and possibly daemons/dæmons

Tags: his-dark-materials, northern-lights, the-amber-spyglass, the-subtle-knife, philip-pullman

Besides the term 'imaginary numbers' being used in the actual books:

> Adam and Eve are like imaginary numbers, like the square root of minus one… If you include it in your equation, you can calculate all manners of things, which cannot be imagined without it.

I could swear there was this interview or something where Pullman said something like

> I might invent the concept of imaginary numbers (or complex numbers?), but then there are all these properties of it that I couldn't have thought of when inventing this concept.

This might then have been used as a justification for an 'I don't know' answer to a question on dæmons like 'What do dæmons when their humans are having sex?'

- **Context**: I'm aiming to use this as an example to say that just because an author has invented a concept doesn't mean the author is the final authority on what is or isn't possible, probably or sensible for a concept, character or plot or point. It's like '[distinction between law maker and law interpreter like 'Law maker should not be law interpreter'?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59447/distinction-between-law-maker-and-law-interpreter-like-law-maker-should-not-be)'.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathOfTheAuthor

Comment: He references this idea multiple times in multiple interviews; https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/nonfiction/interview-philip-pullman/#:~:text=I%E2%80%99ve%20heard%20you%20say%20that%20as,right%20to%20use%20them%20in%20stories.

Comment: Or this one; http://tamaranth.blogspot.com/2000/08/interview-philip-pullman-august-2000.html#:~:text=TB%3A%20But%20you,but%20who%20knows%3F%E2%80%99

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer based on Valorum's comments: Thank you so much Valorum for the comments. God bless you!

The concept is [Death of the Author (tvtropes)](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathOfTheAuthor) : (cf [Wikipedia re essay by the French literary critic and theorist Roland Barthes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Author))

> Death of the Author is a concept from mid-20th Century literary criticism; it holds that an author's intentions and biographical facts (the author's politics, religion, etc) should hold no special weight in determining an interpretation of their writing. This is usually understood as meaning that a writer's views about their own work are no more or less valid than the interpretations of any given reader. Intentions are one thing. What was actually accomplished might be something very different. The logic behind the concept is fairly simple: Books are meant to be read, not written, so the ways readers interpret them are as important and "real" as the author's intention. On the flip side, a lot of authors are unavailable or unwilling to comment on their intentions, and even when they are, they don't always make choices for reasons that make sense or are easily explainable to others (or sometimes even to themselves).

From [here](http://tamaranth.blogspot.com/2000/08/interview-philip-pullman-august-2000.html#:%7E:text=TB%3A%20But%20you,but%20who%20knows%3F%E2%80%99):

> TB: There was one point about demons which – you say, I think, right at the beginning of Northern Lights, that somebody’s got a demon of the same sex as themselves, and this is very rare. Now, does that indicate homosexuality? Or what?
>
> PP: I don’t know. There are plenty of things about my worlds I don’t know, and that’s one of them. It might do! But it might not! Occasionally, no doubt, people do have a demon of the same sex; that might indicate homosexuality, or it might indicate some other sort of gift or quality, such as second sight. I do not know. But I don’t have to know everything about what I write.
>
> TB: But you can make it up as you go along …!
>
> PP: To a certain extent, but then you discover the rules of the world that you’re building as you build them, I’m sure you’re aware of that. I can’t suddenly invent a rule that contradicts all sorts of things that have gone before. Nor do I sit down consciously and work out the rules, draw up the constitution of the world before, as if one were drawing up a constitution of a bowls club or something. It doesn’t happen like that. To some extent, it’s rather like what happens in mathematics, where you discover things – for example, the realm of imaginary numbers. Are they invented or are they discovered? As soon as you discover – as soon as you come across this notion of imaginary numbers, you realise that it is a realm which has its own laws, which has its own things that you can’t contradict and which in turn allow you to do other things with the rest of the natural numbers and so on. It’s partly like that when you’re exploring a world in a book that you’re writing. You’re sort of discovering it as well as inventing it. So there are other things, no doubt, I haven’t yet imagined or thought of about demons. I do find it’s a very rich idea, and right at the end of AS, after 1200 or more pages, I was still discovering new things I could do with this human-demon link. In a way, it’s the best idea I’ve ever had. I don’t know all of it; so, to answer your question, ‘maybe, yes, but who knows?’